# Symsquare Number 01

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues

Symsquare4:
The answer is a square grid which has the same words vertically and horizontally. The clue is a single sentence written in cryptic style and includes one anagram, one hidden word, one Charade and one Double Meaning, all as syntactically separate units. A rank indicator will indicate which word the anagram is:

> A bronze Swede now will show interest to nurture an article on resistance identity with a slippery tire.

Comment: Original designed by me

Comment: What does 'Symsquare4' mean? (Specifically the '4', since the title instead refers to '01'...) Thanks.

Comment: the number of letters in each word that comprises the 4 word answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big thank you to Deusovi for clearing up the issues I had with the grid which should look like the following

> ```
>  C A R E
>  A R I D
>  R I T E
>  E D E N
> ```

Anagram

> *"a slippery tire"*
>  **RITE** = anagram of *tire*

Charade

> *"an article on resistance identity"*
>  "*an article*" = A
>  "*resistance*" = R
>  "*identity*" = ID
>  Overall, giving **ARID**

Double meaning

> *"show interest to nurture"*
>  **CARE** can mean "show interest" or "nurture".

Hidden word

> *"A bronze Swede now"*
>  **EDEN** is hidden inside "swEDE Now"

Original attempt for posterity

> ```
>  P A T E
>  A R I A
>  T I E R
>  E A R N
> ```

Comment: What you've called a "hidden word" is actually a *charade*; a "hidden word" is one where some substring of the clue is taken (usually spanning a gap between two words). "Swede now will show" works that way, giving EDEN, which *almost* works with your current grid...

Comment: ...and that can be fixed by choosing "identity" = ID rather than I, making the last word ARID rather than ARIA.

Comment: @Deusovi Oh my gosh, you are absolutely right! Thank you.