# A Slightly Outdated Symsquare

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues

<sub>Puzzle inspired by [Symsquare Number 01](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119853/symsquare-number-01) series created by @Claude Goeminne</sub>

---

**4x4 Symsquare**
For anyone unfamiliar with a symsquare, the answer is a square grid which has the same words vertically and horizontally. The clue is a single sentence written in the style of cryptic clues and includes one anagram, one hidden word, one Charade and one Double Meaning, all as syntactically separate units. A rank indicator will indicate which word the anagram is:

> Over the last 7 days, feeble recoveries from a deluge of Open Game License electronic messages, leaves abnormally fowl taste in consumers mouths.

Comment: I think I have an answer although there are several words in the sentence not used. Is that expected?

Comment: @hexomino yes that is expected, sorry for any confusion still working on cryptic clue style

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is the solution

> ```
>  F L O W
>  L U G E
>  O G L E
>  W E E K
> ```

Double definition

> *"Over the last 7 days, feeble"*
>  **WEEK** - where we use *feeble* to clue the homophone *weak*.

Hidden word

> *"recoveries from a deluge"*
>  **LUGE** - hidden inside deLUGE.

Charade

> *"Open Game License electronic messages"*
>  **OGLE** - Open Game Licence is OGL and electronic messages would be *e*-messages.

Anagram

> *"abnormally fowl"*
>  **FLOW** - anagram of *fowl*